# how to pass in multiple arguments to prompt in bash script?

Tags: bash, unix

In my bash script, I'm invoking a commands that prompts for 2 answers (in a row) from STDin. How do I pipe in answers to both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just separate the input into two lines. e,g ,

```
cat file.txt | your_command
```

where `file.txt` could have

```
input1
input2
```

Comment: That's a [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). Simply use `your_command < file.txt` instead of `cat`.

Comment: @dogbane this is just an example showing that you can pipe in the output of any command. The OP asked about piping in and so I replied this way.

Answer (score 8):

Use a heredoc as shown below:

```
$ myscript.sh << EOF
answer1
answer2
EOF
```

Comment: Perhaps better to use quotes around the label `<< "EOF"` to avoid expansions by the shell within the here-doc?